# Difference between "valued" and "valuable"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, synonyms

Please explain the difference between "valued" and "valuable" when talking about goods. Which of them should be used to indicate intangible value and which to indicate price? For example, if a product is very useful and inexpensive, is it "valued" or "valuable"?

Comment: Well, technically "valuable" means capable of having a value assigned, while "valued" means having had a value assigned.

Comment: @HotLicks: It may be capable of having a value assigned, but that is only because it **has value**. Something that has value is valuable. Assignment of a specific value (e.g. a grade or a quantity of money) is a way to indicate that something has value (is valuable), and it can serve as proof that it is valuable, but it is not what makes the item valuable. Assigning value is especially a way to measure *how* valuable it is considered to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Valuable** means something is likely to be valued by a lot of people.

**Valued** means it's definitely already valued by some people.

If a product is inexpensive, it may be *valued* by those who own it, but it can hardly be *valuable*.

Answer (score 2):

Typical uses of **valued** are:

> The item was **valued** at $5000

… which means that it was judged to be worth $5000.

> He was a **valued** member of the team

… which means that he was a useful member whose value to the team is appreciated by others.

Typical uses of **valuable** are:

> It was a **valuable** item, being valued at $5000.

… "valuable" here meaning *worth a lot of money*.

> He was a **valuable** member of the team.

… meaning pretty much the same as before, except that there's no implication that others *appreciate* his value.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the accepted answer, by @Ricky.

I would say that a thing that is *valuable* **has value**. It is not that it is "likely" to have value or that "many people" have valued it. It is enough that it has value for one person for it to be valuable to that person.

See the examples given in the answer by @ralph.m.

> Adjective: **valuable**  val-yoo-u-bul
>
> 1. Having great material or monetary value especially for use or exchange
>
>    "a valuable diamond"
> 2. Having worth, merit or value
>
>    "a valuable friend";
>
>    - worthful

-- [WordWeb](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=valuable)

> Adjective: **valued**  val-yood
>
> 1. (usually used in combination) having value of a specified kind
>
>    "triple-valued"
> 2. Held in great esteem for admirable qualities especially of an intrinsic nature
>
>    "a valued friend";
>
>    - precious

-- [WordWeb](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=valued)

Answer (score -4):

-"This object looks valuable, I wonder how much it is worth."
-"I'll tell you, it is valued at £20."

Comment: Please explain your answer in full. How does this demonstrate the difference between the two words?